# How to change size of Badge?

Tags: reactjs

I'm using react-boostrap and I'm trying to customize bagde.

```
import Badge from 'react-bootstrap/Badge';
<Badge pill variant="primary" size="small">MyBadge</Badge>
```

why does size= "small" is don't working?

Comment: [Bootstrap Badges](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/badge/) have only one size; there is no "small".

Comment: Badges scale to match the size of the immediate parent element by using relative font sizing and em units.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `size` argument for a badge in `react-bootstrap`: https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/badge/

The size depends on the current font size, see the first example in the [documentation](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/badge/).

Answer (score 0):

you can customize the fontSize
`<Badge style={{fontSize: 16}}>`

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in other answers, `Badge` does not have a `size` attribute.

A workaround to this can be adding **padding**, which will increase the size of the element without increasing its font size.

Example:

```
<Badge pill variant="primary" style={{ padding: '0.5rem' }}>MyBadge</Badge>
     
                                        ^^^
```

Or more conveniently using [bootstrap spacing classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/utilities/spacing/):

```
<Badge pill variant="primary" className='p-2'>MyBadge</Badge>
              
                                     ^^^
```

Try it in [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/8mjyw).